# In MVC where do you put a custom class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, directory-structure

Let's say you need to make a custom class that will be used by your controller.

```
class mycontroller extends main_controller
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $c = new my_custom_class();
    }
}
```

`my_custom_class` is not a model/view/controller, it's a standalone class. What is the best practice on where (what folder) to put the file of `my_custom_class.php`? Should it simply be placed in an arbitrary folder (i.e., `/custom_classes/`) or is there a best practice when using MVC?

Comment: Imo, it depends on what this custom class is actually doing.

Comment: Model is the best fit, but you could further separate it ie /classes/helpers/MyHelper.php

Comment: you can using bisnes logic in library and use this library in your class, but you need call this class as framework because you have library folder, and your framework have realisation algorithm for load class and save in registry, and realisation autoloading classes from library directory. for example you run `composer update` and composer download libraries to vendor after generate autoload class, for bootstrap this classes in you project.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what those "custom classes" are actually for. In one of more recent projects my directory structure looked like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGVI9.png

The custom classes, that were interacted with by controllers, usually were various services and went in `/src/model/services` directory.

I also had two locations for infrastructure-level classes (like various factories/builders and some abstract classes for data structures). Those ended up in either in  `/src/components`
or `/src/applications/<app>/components` directories.

What you are seeing in your own project might be a *"code smell"* analogue, but for application architecture. It might be an indication, that you have been pushing application logic in the controllers, where it shouldn't be.